# Nullpointer Exception Error - Trying to get text from JTextArea

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to get the text from `JTextArea` stored into a variable which is then used in combination with `FileWriter/BufferedWriter` to save the content in a file.
It works with a normal string like:

```
String stored = "Example";
```

But I always get a nullpointer exception error trying to use the following:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    HeadBar retrieve = new HeadBar();
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
      String stored = retrieve.txtarea.getText();
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("H:/UserInput.txt");
      bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      bw.write(stored);
      bw.flush();
      System.out.println("Text saved successfully.");

    } catch (IOException ex){
      System.out.println("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
});
```

A part of `Headbar` class in a method:

```
txtarea = new JTextArea();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.ipady = 800;
c.weighty = 5.0;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridwidth = 20;
c.gridy = 20;
panel.add(txtarea, c);
```

What did I do wrong or is `getText()` the wrong method?

Comment: Could you post the code for your HeaderBar class please. Also, which line causes the NPE ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Then, you should have looked the stacktrace which would have told you on which line the error occurred. It would have been useful to include it in your post.

Now, even without the stacktrace, I can assume that the NPE is caused by `retrieve.txtarea.getText();`. As you instanciated `retrieve` without setting any `txtarea`, I suppose that `textarea` is null, hence the NPE.